# Can I check-in Carton Box on a Qantas Flight?

Tags: air-travel, australia, domestic-travel, qantas

I'm going to take a domestic flight from Melbourne to Sydney within the upcoming days. However, I would like to take a carton box with the total dimension of 61 inches (155cm) on Qantas airline as a checked bag. Do you think they will allow carton boxes to be checked in? Does that size is fine for the domestic flight?

Comment: The answer will depend upon your Qantas' ticket's travel class, as well as the weight of the box you propose to check. See "Australian Domestic flights" on [this Qantas page](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage.html). Further down that same page, "Packing your baggage"   says the bagge must be "packed securely and appropriately." You can also view your baggage allowances at Qantas' [Manage Booking page](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/manage-booking.html).

Comment: Remember: any piece of luggage will be thrown around, and will have other luggage thrown onto it and piled onto it. It’s not unusual for a hundred kg to sit on top of any piece of luggage. Also luggage will often be subject to the elements (I.e. rain, wind, hail…) while carried to or from the plane. Will your cardboard box will able to withstand all of this? A well packed cardboard box could. Others would just crumble.

Answer (score 5):

> Does that size is fine for the domestic flight?

No. According to https://www.qantas.com/au/en/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage.html#checked-baggage-allowance the size limit for domestic flights is 140cm (55in). It's unclear whether they don't accept larger bags at all or simply charge you extra. You may have to call to find out.

This also depends partially on your specific ticket and your status (if any) with Qantas.

> Do you think they will allow carton boxes to be checked in?

Probably yes. Most airlines will accept carton boxes. They may reject it if it feels particular flimsy. They may also require you to sign a waiver so that they are not liable for any damage.

Checked luggage is NOT treated gently. You really want to make sure that the carton is sturdy and any contents are well padded. Not a good choice for anything fragile or breakable.

Comment: Many people will either wrap the box in plastic or transport it in a thin bag, possibly taped close to the box.